# is there a better way of sending a list of int over a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, asynchronous, deserialization

I want to send a list of int (can be 10 to 1000 ints) over tcp

I do send to the client how many bytes it should receive before parsing the data.

I also use the BeginSend / BeginReceive pattern (one thread for each).

I came up with this simple code to do what I want

```
const int sizeOfInt = sizeof(int);
int index = 0;

var OriginalList = new List<int>();
OriginalList.Add(1);
OriginalList.Add(42);
//.....
OriginalList.Add(9001);


//prepare and send the ArrayOfByte over the wire
var ArrayOfByte = new byte[OriginalList.Count * sizeOfInt];

foreach (var item in OriginalList)
{
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(item), 0, ArrayOfByte, index, sizeOfInt);

    index += sizeOfInt;
}
//socket.BeginSend(ArrayOfByte....


//socket.BeginReceive(ArrayOfByte....
//On receive move it into a List<int>
int length = ArrayOfByte.Length;

var CopyOfList = new List<int>(length / sizeOfInt);

for (index = 0; index < length; index += sizeOfInt)
{
    CopyOfList.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(ArrayOfByte, index));
}
```

is there a better way / faster way of doing this?

Comment: It appears your code assumes `socket.receive(ArrayOfByte)` receives the array in one call. This is not always true! Pretend you are writing to a file on the hard drive, closing the program then re-opening it, how does the second run know how many bytes where written on your first `.Write(` call? Network reads have the same problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i removed the socket part of the code but i do manage how many bytes should arrive before parsing it on the other side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thoughts:

that creates a *lot* of unnecessary small `byte[]` instances to collect; that's a *bit* of a pain from the `BitConverter` API, but it can be avoided; I'd probably just use bit-ops (shift / and) to write the bytes, since that avoids CPU-endianness issues, but it could also be done with `unsafe` very efficiently; a `BinaryWriter` would also work

CPU endianness

you don't actually need a `byte[]` for all the contents; you can just write in sequence, although note that if you have socket buffering disabled (`NoDelay` etc) you probably want to think about what is a *reasonable size* for packets

if you know more information about the likely integers, more efficient representations might be available - for example, "varint" encoding (basically, similar to how UTF-8 encodes low characters in single bytes, and uses multi-byte for high characters)

for the consumer to process the data effectively, you should also send the number of elements or the payload size of the elements, so the receiver knows when a logical frame has been received - unless there is only one message on the socket

---

Some example bit-op based socket code:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var val in list) {
    buffer[index++] = (byte)val;
    buffer[index++] = (byte)(val >> 8);
    buffer[index++] = (byte)(val >> 16);
    buffer[index++] = (byte)(val >> 24);

    if(index == buffer.Length) { // flush buffer
        socket.Write(buffer, 0, index);
        index = 0;
    }
}
if(index != 0) { // final flush
    socket.Write(buffer, 0, index);
}
```

The read code needs to ensure there are some entire number of values before starting, then:

```
while(index < availableBytes) {
    int val = buffer[index++] | (buffer[index++] << 8)
            | (buffer[index++] << 16) | (buffer[index++] << 24);
    list.Add(val);
}
```

Comment: I just looked at the bitconverter with ILSpy and I like the idea of removing the bitconverter and I will look at the socket buffering

Comment: for the solution of using bit-ops, would you write 4 lines of code or simply write a for-loop (I think the loop would be overkill but i prefer asking)

Comment: the bit-ops is about 3x faster than the bitconverter and buffering socket seem to be very easy to implement so i will try and see how it goes in my current codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Faster: probably not (you could optimise your sends to match network packet size, but that won't gain you much). Doing everything asynchronously would use fewer system resources (not blocking threads), but again wouldn't be faster.

Better: for a start tell the other end how much data you are sending (a separate process, even on the same machine will not have access to `ArrayOfByte` from the sender to size the receive); second break things up into separate functions each with a single purpose.

Comment: I added more information in my question, I didn't think of adding how I was managing the socket.